# Filtering a two-dimensional array and creating new arrays with its data

Tags: java, arrays

Tell me please, how is it possible to implement the following task?
I need to filter the array by the last value of the string, put it in a new array.
Those. In this example, 1 row should be in 1 array, and in the second, 2 others.
I checked the array for the presence of a specific value like I did

```
boolean x  = Arrays.asList(matrixA).contains("a");
```

But I can not figure out how to proceed further and write the whole line into a new array?

```
public class arr {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[][] matrixA = {
                {"1", "1", "a"},
                {"2", "2", "c"},
                {"3", "3", "c"}};

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {


                boolean x  = Arrays.asList(matrixA).contains("a");
                if (x==true)
                {

                }


                boolean c  = Arrays.asList(matrixA).contains("c");
                if (c==true)
                {

                }

                System.out.print(matrixA[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end there must be 2 arrays

```
    Arr1{
     {"1", "1", "a"}};
    Arr2{
     {"2", "2", "c"},
     {"3", "3", "c"}};
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to group by last value in the array instead of filtering by it. Is that the case?

Comment: You have to create this 2 arrays and put the lines in. What is your actual problem?